# Steam won't start on Ubuntu 14.04.1

Tags: 14.04, steam

When I click on the icon from the Launcher, nothing happens. When I enter 'steam' in Terminal, I get this:

```
    steam
Running Steam on ubuntu 14.04 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(0_client)
Uploading dump (out-of-process) [proxy '']
/tmp/dumps/crash_20140829154109_1.dmp
Finished uploading minidump (out-of-process): success = no
error: libcurl.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
/home/stefan/.local/share/Steam/steam.sh: line 730:  6206 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) $STEAM_DEBUGGER "$STEAMROOT/$STEAMEXEPATH" "$@"
mv: cannot stat ‘/home/stefan/.steam/registry.vdf’: No such file or directory
Installing bootstrap /home/stefan/.local/share/Steam/bootstrap.tar.xz
Reset complete!
Restarting Steam by request...
Running Steam on ubuntu 14.04 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME has been set by the user to: /home/stefan/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(0_client)
Uploading dump (out-of-process) [proxy '']
/tmp/dumps/crash_20140829154110_1.dmp
Finished uploading minidump (out-of-process): success = no
error: libcurl.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
/home/stefan/.local/share/Steam/steam.sh: line 730:  6332 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) $STEAM_DEBUGGER "$STEAMROOT/$STEAMEXEPATH" "$@"
```

What to do? :( I installed Steam from the Ubuntu Software Center.

Answer (score 3):

This will sound crazy, but the solution is to

1. uninstall your Nvidia or AMD driver

   - I.e. `sudo apt-get purge fglrx*` or `sudo apt-get purge nvidia-*`
2. reboot
3. start Steam and let it update, while using the open drivers
4. reinstall your proprietary driver
5. and finally reboot again.

Steam has some kind of issue with the proprietary AMD/Nvidia drivers which cause the problem. For more info, have a look here: https://github.com/ValveSoftware/steam-for-linux/issues/3248

Comment: After installing libcurl:i386 and switching the Xorg driver in Additional Drivers (didn't bother to reboot), I was able to successfully run steam after removing `~/.steam` - thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I don't run steam, so cannot try this, but a suggestion from the [steam community](http://steamcommunity.com/app/222880/discussions/2/35221584697468958/) is that you need to add the libcurl module to your system.

The command suggested is

`sudo apt-get install libcurl3:i386`

Comment: I already tried this, but it didn't work.

Comment: Steam also needs curl itself