# Steam won't start Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, steam

**I have just installed Ubuntu 14.04, and steam launches into this!** (I have required this through running the **steam** command in the terminal.

```
Running Steam on ubuntu 14.04 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1427176184)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1427176184)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1427176184)
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "overlay-scrollbar"
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "unity-gtk-module"
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/10-scale-bitmap-fonts.conf", line 70: non-double matrix element
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/10-scale-bitmap-fonts.conf", line 70: non-double matrix element
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/10-scale-bitmap-fonts.conf", line 78: saw unknown, expected number
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1427176184)
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "overlay-scrollbar"
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "unity-gtk-module"
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steamwebhelper)/version(20150323200504)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steamwebhelper)/version(1427141104)
[0405/174215:ERROR:nss_util.cc(1018)] Failed to load NSS libraries.
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steamwebhelper)/version(20150323200504)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steamwebhelper)/version(1427176184)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steamwebhelper)/version(1427176184)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1427176184)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1427176184)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1427176184)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1427176184)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1427176184)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1427176184)
FillInMachineIDInfo took a total of 0 milliseconds
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1427176184)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1427176184)
[0405/174216:ERROR:renderer_main.cc(227)] Running without renderer sandbox
[0405/174216:ERROR:renderer_main.cc(227)] Running without renderer sandbox
LLVM ERROR: Do not know how to split the result of this operator!

Assert( Assertion Failed: Bad thread local ):/home/buildbot/buildslave_steam/steam_rel_client_ubuntu12_linux/build/src/tier0/threadtools.cpp:2693

Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1427176184)
assert_20150405174217_14.dmp[11594]: Uploading dump (out-of-process)
/tmp/dumps/assert_20150405174217_14.dmp
/home/buildbot/buildslave_steam/steam_rel_client_ubuntu12_linux/build/src/tier1/../tier1/fileio.cpp (4008) : Assertion Failed: CFileWriterThread: pending file writer content_log.txt
Assert( Assertion Failed: CFileWriterThread: pending file writer content_log.txt ):/home/buildbot/buildslave_steam/steam_rel_client_ubuntu12_linux/build/src/tier1/../tier1/fileio.cpp:4008

Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1427176184)
/home/buildbot/buildslave_steam/steam_rel_client_ubuntu12_linux/build/src/tier1/../tier1/fileio.cpp (4008) : Assertion Failed: CFileWriterThread: pending file writer connection_log.txt
crash_20150405174217_16.dmp[11597]: Uploading dump (out-of-process)
/tmp/dumps/crash_20150405174217_16.dmp
assert_20150405174214_1.dmp[11600]: Uploading dump (out-of-process)
/tmp/dumps/assert_20150405174214_1.dmp
/home/nitridetech/.local/share/Steam/steam.sh: line 757: 11540 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) $STEAM_DEBUGGER "$STEAMROOT/$STEAMEXEPATH" "$@"
[0405/174217:WARNING:content_browser_client.cc(499)] No browser info matching frame process id 1 and routing id 1
[0405/174217:WARNING:content_browser_client.cc(499)] No browser info matching frame process id 2 and routing id 1
assert_20150405174217_14.dmp[11594]: Finished uploading minidump (out-of-process): success = yes
assert_20150405174217_14.dmp[11594]: response: CrashID=bp-2a72e61e-52f4-46a1-ac0b-5ce122150405
assert_20150405174217_14.dmp[11594]: file ''/tmp/dumps/assert_20150405174217_14.dmp'', upload yes: ''CrashID=bp-2a72e61e-52f4-46a1-ac0b-5ce122150405''
crash_20150405174217_16.dmp[11597]: Finished uploading minidump (out-of-process): success = yes
crash_20150405174217_16.dmp[11597]: response: CrashID=bp-5c5f92cf-f987-43db-8e9a-cd3e32150405
crash_20150405174217_16.dmp[11597]: file ''/tmp/dumps/crash_20150405174217_16.dmp'', upload yes: ''CrashID=bp-5c5f92cf-f987-43db-8e9a-cd3e32150405''
assert_20150405174214_1.dmp[11600]: Finished uploading minidump (out-of-process): success = yes
assert_20150405174214_1.dmp[11600]: response: CrashID=bp-0d1f681e-520b-4f27-95ee-b41a72150405
assert_20150405174214_1.dmp[11600]: file ''/tmp/dumps/assert_20150405174214_1.dmp'', upload yes: ''CrashID=bp-0d1f681e-520b-4f27-95ee-b41a72150405''
```

Comment: Are the `overlay-scrollbar` and `unity-gtk-module` packages installed? Check with `dpkg -l overlay-scrollbar`

Comment: See [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/536280/77449) Possible duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/517596/steam-wont-start-on-ubuntu-14-04-1

Comment: What GPU and video driver are you using?